# Selecting folders_name in mySQL query + the COUNT() of files in each folder

Tags: mysql

My mySql code is the following:

It selects `folder_names` of a particular **user**,
but I also want the `COUNT()` of the files in each folder.

This code is ok, but the `COUNT()` always returns the number of folders (in my case 6).

How can I get this code to COUNT the **right number** of files in each folder?

```
SELECT fo.* , COUNT(f.file_id)
FROM folders fo
LEFT JOIN files f ON f.folder_id = fo.folder_id
WHERE fo.user_id = :user_id
GROUP BY fo.folder_id
ORDER BY fo.folder_name ASC
```

Now it works !!!!!!!
Thanks to Bill Karwin !!

Tables

```
folders -> folder_id, user_id, folder_name, folder_icon_id, folder_description.

files -> file_id, folder_id, user_id, filename, file_icon, file_description.
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to GROUP BY folder_id in order to get that count right

Comment: Yes, my bad. But it still shows "6" (total number of folders) on each line

Comment: To ellaborate more, the query "ALMOST WORKS", but the COUNT(f.file_id) shows 6 for each line, which is total number of files that this uses has.....

Comment: Shouldn't you join files to folders `ON f.folder_id = fo.folder_id`?

Comment: Yes! That was it! I did that before, but the query was incomplete at the time....you saved my query. 3 Heineken for you !!!! On the house :))) thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Your joining clause should be `folder_id`. As if a `user` has 5 files then all the folders with same `user_id` will show the same count if you join based on `user_id`.

```
SELECT fo.* , COUNT(f.file_id)
FROM folders fo
LEFT JOIN files f ON f.folder_id = fo.folder_id 
WHERE fo.user_id = :user_id
GROUP BY fo.folder_id
ORDER BY fo.folder_name ASC
```